# CSS @media in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a little help. I creates a nav menu in html an css (with specific media query), and the javascript (jquery) I wrote code that looks like this:

```
var x = $('#nav-menu > ul').children().length;
alert(x);

$('#nav-menu > ul li').css(width, x);
```

But the last line in the code I want change in the specific media query.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use JavaScript and inline styles (the `.css()` method), but just the CSS file? If you need to switch it on/off, use a class that can be removed/added by JS.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.css` creates an inline style and doesn't actually change the CSS file that contains the rules being applied. Instead, create a class and add a rule in the media query for the properties that you want to change, and use `.addClass` and `removeClass` in your JavaScript as needed.

Edit: just saw that bergi's comment is basically the same idea. Hope this helps understand why.